# Hashmap is value is null everytimes

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I am creating a hashmap where my key is string and value is a list. From excel i am reading all the row values and adding to a list. Then list is mapped to the key. But when try to the value for a key its returning null. Please let me know what is wrong in the code.

```
    private static void FCToProjectsMapping(String RefFilename)
  {
    System.out.println(RefFilename);

    Workbook wb = null;
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> MappingFCInProjects = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

    try
    {
      if (RefFilename == null || RefFilename.isEmpty()) 
      {
        System.out.println("Workbook is empty or Not available");
      }
      try
      {
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(RefFilename));
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
        System.out.println(e);
      }

      Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet0");

      int TotalColumnNo = sheet.getRow(1).getLastCellNum();

      for (int ColNo = 2; ColNo < TotalColumnNo; ColNo++)
      {
        ArrayList<String> itemList=new ArrayList<String>();

        String FCNAME = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(ColNo).getStringCellValue().trim();
        String ClassificationNAME = sheet.getRow(2).getCell(ColNo).getStringCellValue().trim();
        String AltNo = sheet.getRow(3).getCell(ColNo).getStringCellValue().trim();
        String Version = FCNAME + "/" + AltNo + "_" + ClassificationNAME;

        for (int RowNo=5; RowNo <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); RowNo++)
        {
          if(sheet.getRow(RowNo).getCell(ColNo)!=null && !sheet.getRow(RowNo).getCell(ColNo).getStringCellValue().isEmpty())
          { 
              String ProjectName = "";

              if(sheet.getRow(RowNo).getCell(ColNo)!=null && !sheet.getRow(RowNo).getCell(ColNo).getStringCellValue().isEmpty())
              { 
                ProjectName = sheet.getRow(RowNo).getCell(1).getStringCellValue().trim();               
                itemList.add(ProjectName);
              }
          }
        }
        if(!MappingFCInProjects.containsKey(Version))
        {
          MappingFCInProjects.put(Version, itemList); 
        }
        itemList.clear();
      }          
      wb.close();      

    }
    catch(Exception error)
    {
      System.out.println("Error occured in FCToProjectsMapping function is "+ error);
    }

  }
```

Comment: debug and check is your code adding some value to the arraylist or not .

Answer (score 1):

You insert `itemList` into the map, then you clear it, so now you have an empty list in the map. The `put(Version, itemList)` call doesn't copy the list, it inserts the list itself.

Remove the `itemList.clear();` line and that part of the code will work.

Other issues:

- You should use `new XSSFWorkbook(new File(RefFilename))` so you don't load the entire file into memory.
- You should remove the `try-catch` around the `new XSSFWorkbook` call, and let the `catch` at the end handle it.
- Actually, you should use *try-with-resources*:

  ```
  if (RefFilename == null || RefFilename.isEmpty()) 
  {
    System.out.println("Workbook is empty or Not available");
    return; // <== add this to prevent NullPointerException
  }
  try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new File(RefFilename)))
  {
    ...
  ```
- Since you just discard `itemList` without using it, you should do the following before the `RowNo` loop:

  ```
  if (! MappingFCInProjects.containsKey(Version))
  {
    continue; // skip processing of column
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is null is because when you create a new list and you put items in it you clear the same list.
for (int ColNo = 2; ColNo < TotalColumnNo; ColNo++) {
                ArrayList itemList = new ArrayList(); // **AT THIS LINE YOU CREATE A LIST**

```
            String FCNAME = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(ColNo).getStringCellValue().trim();
            String ClassificationNAME = sheet.getRow(2).getCell(ColNo).getStringCellValue().trim();
            String AltNo = sheet.getRow(3).getCell(ColNo).getStringCellValue().trim();
            String Version = FCNAME + "/" + AltNo + "_" + ClassificationNAME;

            for (int RowNo = 5; RowNo <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); RowNo++) {
                if (sheet.getRow(RowNo).getCell(ColNo) != null
                        && !sheet.getRow(RowNo).getCell(ColNo).getStringCellValue().isEmpty()) {
                    String ProjectName = "";

                    if (sheet.getRow(RowNo).getCell(ColNo) != null
                            && !sheet.getRow(RowNo).getCell(ColNo).getStringCellValue().isEmpty()) {
                        ProjectName = sheet.getRow(RowNo).getCell(1).getStringCellValue().trim();
                        itemList.add(ProjectName);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!MappingFCInProjects.containsKey(Version)) {
                MappingFCInProjects.put(Version, itemList);
            }
            itemList.clear();//YOU CLEAR THE SAME INSTANCE
        }
```

//you should comment the line itemList.clear for it to work